# Determining Source Line and File of function reference - How does Firebug do it?

Tags: javascript, firebug, intellisense

Brief introduction:

I'm attempting to get at line number of function definition for parsing documentation comments on only public stuff.  I've gotten to the point where I can find the name of the function and if I so wanted I could execute the function, but I can't seem to figure out any way to pull out line number information.  Note: this is purely for documentation purposes so cross-browser isn't necessary.

I know firebug (but not firebug lite so I don't know how possible this is) shows you the line number and script location of a referenced function on mouseover.  I looked through the firebug source and got as far as finding they call (`domPanel.js:536`), but can't seem to find this "addMember" function anywhere in their source:

```
this.addMember(object, "userFunction", userFuncs, name, val, level, 0, context);
```

It may be that this just isn't possible to determine.  My fallbacks are using `[userfunction].name` and `[userfunction].toSource()` and then attempt to match source to source.  But I would like to avoid these if possible since the name could be non-unique and the toSource() gives the source post-processing.  Maybe there is a way to tie into the firebug api?

Minimal Explanation Code:

[Note the goal would be to get this information: `window.MyWindowObject.PublicFunction: script.js line 3`]

script.js

```
(function () {

    function referencedFunction() {
       ///<summary>Sample XML Doc Comment</summary>
       alert('well hello there!');
    }

    var publicObject = window.MyWindowObject || {};
    publicObject.PublicFunction = referencedFunction;

    window.MyWindowObject = publicObject;
}());
```

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

EDIT: for anyone who finds this on a search later here is some other useful related info that I've found:

Stacktrace.js: https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace
 - Pretty close but not quite what I want since it doesn't seem to get the final function's location.  The example on their website is not correct (though the demo "looks" like what I wanted)

In chrome (and IE9): `[userfunction].toString()` preserves comments (does not in firefox), which is what I will probably end up using.  I was going to use firefox's `[userfunction]`.toSource() but this looks like browser-manipulated source of the function.  firefox's `[userfunction]`.toString() appears to preserve code, but strips comments

Comment: Not sure, but I think Firebug hooks directly into FF's javascript interpreter - something you can't do without building a browser extension.

Comment: @Flambino has it right: Firebug has special access to stuff like this thanks to it being a browser plugin. If you need proof of this, look at Firebug Lite, which runs as plain Javascript-in-the-browser; it doesn't have a JS debugger feature because that can't be done without the privileges it gets from being a plug-in. (the Firebug Lite documentation actually states this explicitly)

Comment: @Spudley: I noted in my question I've already looked at firebug lite and understand the limitations of javascript but was still asking whether there is any way to do this.  I was thinking maybe something with forcing exceptions since in some browsers stack traces include the information I am looking for, but I have not found any solution yet so therefore the question.

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: Well, if Firebug Lite hasn't found a way of doing it, it's probably either extremely diffcult or downright impossible to make it work... unless you write an actual javascript interpreter in javascript or something, but that's going a little far, wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: @Flambino: Yep, I'm willing to take the "It's impossible in all the reasonable browsers I could check" answer.  Just thought I'd throw it out there in case someone else has tried stuff.  I'm going to post useful information above.

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: You can also use `Object.prototype.toString.call(someFunc)` to get the source code of a function. I don't know if that's more similar from browser to browser

Comment: @Flambino: that one seems to consistently return "[object Function]"

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: Arh, sorry. You're right. I got it mixed up with a different problem I once had. Ignore what I said. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug has access to protected Chrome features that ordinary JS does not.

But, JS can still access, the raw `<script>` source, with comments intact, as long as the same-origin policy does not block access.

For example, this code will get the raw source of all embedded scripts and any scripts loaded from the same domain. :

```
var scipts = document.querySelectorAll ('script');

for (var J = 0, L = scipts.length;  J < L;  ++J) {
    console.log ('Number: ', J);
    var node    = scipts[J];
    if (!node)  continue;

    if (node.src) {
        //$.get (node.src, function (data) {console.log ('Text: ', data); } );
        try {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open ('GET', node.src, false);
            req.send (null);
            if (req.status == 200  ||  req.status == 304)
                console.log ('Text: ', req.responseText);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log (err);
        }
    }
    else if (node.innerHTML) {
        console.log ('Text: ', node.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

The raw script can then be parsed for line numbers and function definitions, etc.

Comment: It's all internal so I'm not too worried about X-domain.  Good to know though

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential solution that I haven't tested. A couple years ago, there was a [security exploit](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/) that allowed JavaScript to redeclare constructors of native objects. [John Walker](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aFgJx3T1lfWMJ%3adirectwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html%20http://getahead.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com) gave this example:

```
function Array() {
    this[1] = 50;
}
var a = [40];
alert(a[0] + a[1]); // Gives 90
```

In the same vein, perhaps it's possible to redeclare the function declaration in the browsers where the exploit exists?

```
function Function() {
    // Should give the stack trace, complete with line number?
    alert(new Error().stack); 
}

window.x = function () {}
```

I don't have the necessary browsers (John Resig cites Firefox 2, Opera 9, and Safari 3 as browsers where the Array exploit works), so I can't test it, but maybe this is a place to start?