# get line number and filename for a log output

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Is it possible to get the line number and file for each log output ?

For example:

```
  var winston = require('winston');

  winston.log('info', 'some message!'); // this is at line 4 of myfile.js
```

should specify in log file that 'some message' came from myFile.js line 4.

Comment: This question is very similar to what you are hoping to accomplish, unless you're hoping to log explicitly with winston. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172455/get-name-and-line-of-calling-function-in-node-js

Answer (score 17):

You can pass the file name as `label` and you can get the file name from callingModule.

Create `logger.js` file and code like

```
var winston = require('winston');
var getLabel = function (callingModule) {
    var parts = callingModule.filename.split('/');
    return parts[parts.length - 2] + '/' + parts.pop();
};

module.exports = function (callingModule) {
    return new winston.Logger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
                label: getLabel(callingModule),
                json: false,
                timestamp: true,
                depth:true,
                colorize:true
            })
        ]
    });
};
```

Now Here your test file

```
var logger = require('./logger')(module);
function test() {
    logger.info('test logger');
}
test();
```

and if you run test file than the output looks like

```
2017-07-08T07:15:20.671Z - info: [utils/test.js] test logger
```

Comment: i am passing the module but the problem is that i am not able to get the filename as undefined.

Comment: You can check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702679/getting-undefined-for-the-filename-even-though-file-name-is-passed

Comment: also how can we use the morgan , here. All the solutions shows without morgan , how can we use the morgan . I have raised a question for it. Do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718192/stream-write-is-not-a-function-when-using-morgan-with-logger

Comment: use path.sep instead of using '/' to split the path.
const path = require('path');

Comment: I've used this in a large project with strapi...we end up getting a maxEventEmitters warning after a point. There's possibly a memory leak here.

Comment: looks like we are create new Logger Instance for every file with `new winston.Logger`

Comment: Yes I also faced maxEventEmitters warning in large project because it is creating new logger instance for each file which is very bad. do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 4):

winston didn't have the plan to do that due to performance concerns. Please [check here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/200) for detailed information.

I tried https://github.com/baryon/tracer but it isn't good, e.g. line number is incorrect from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

### Update (for Winston 3.x)

I also created a [gist for the following code](https://gist.github.com/alfasin/ddd5b559658751af35f765a7a690f777):

```
const { format } = require('winston');
const { combine, colorize, timestamp, printf } = format;

/**
 * /**
 * Use CallSite to extract filename and number, for more info read: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces
 * @param numberOfLinesToFetch - optional, when we want more than one line back from the stacktrace
 * @returns {string|null} filename and line number separated by a colon, if numberOfLinesToFetch > 1 we'll return a string
 * that represents multiple CallSites (representing the latest calls in the stacktrace)
 *
 */
const getFileNameAndLineNumber = function getFileNameAndLineNumber (numberOfLinesToFetch = 1) {
    const oldStackTrace = Error.prepareStackTrace;

    const boilerplateLines = line => line &&
        line.getFileName() &&
        (line.getFileName().indexOf('<My Module Name>') &&
        (line.getFileName().indexOf('/node_modules/') < 0));

    try {
        // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
        Error.prepareStackTrace = (err, structuredStackTrace) => structuredStackTrace;
        Error.captureStackTrace(this);
        // we need to "peel" the first CallSites (frames) in order to get to the caller we're looking for
        // in our case we're removing frames that come from logger module or from winston
        const callSites = this.stack.filter(boilerplateLines);
        if (callSites.length === 0) {
            // bail gracefully: even though we shouldn't get here, we don't want to crash for a log print!
            return null;
        }
        const results = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLinesToFetch; i++) {
            const callSite = callSites[i];
            let fileName = callSite.getFileName();
            fileName = fileName.includes(BASE_DIR_NAME) ? fileName.substring(BASE_DIR_NAME.length + 1) : fileName;
            results.push(fileName + ':' + callSite.getLineNumber());
        }
        return results.join('\n');
    } finally {
        Error.prepareStackTrace = oldStackTrace;
    }
};

function humanReadableFormatter ({ level, message, ...metadata }) {
    const filename = getFileNameAndLineNumber();
    return `[${level}] [${filename}] ${message} ${JSON.stringify(metadata)}`;
}    

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'info',
            handleExceptions: true,
            humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: { all: true },
            stderrLevels: ['error', 'alert', 'critical'],
            format: combine(
                colorize(),
                timestamp(),
                humanReadableFormatter,
            ),
        })
    ]
});
```

### Original Answer (for Winston 2.x)

I'm using winston 2.x (but the same solution will work for winston 3.x) and [that's the way](https://gist.github.com/alfasin/887d3622a39c90de528a9a48d5b7f0c3) I'm logging the filename and linenumber of the caller:

**IMPORTANT**: pay attention to the embedded code comments!

```
/**
 * Use CallSite to extract filename and number
 * @returns {string} filename and line number separated by a colon
 */
const getFileNameAndLineNumber = () => {
    const oldStackTrace = Error.prepareStackTrace;
    try {
        // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
        Error.prepareStackTrace = (err, structuredStackTrace) => structuredStackTrace;
        Error.captureStackTrace(this);
        // in this example I needed to "peel" the first 10 CallSites in order to get to the caller we're looking for, hence the magic number 11
        // in your code, the number of stacks depends on the levels of abstractions you're using, which mainly depends on winston version!
        // so I advise you to put a breakpoint here and see if you need to adjust the number!
        return this.stack[11].getFileName() + ':' + this.stack[11].getLineNumber();
    } finally {
        Error.prepareStackTrace = oldStackTrace;
    }
};
```

And (a simplified version of) the formatter function:

```
function humanReadableFormatter ({level, message}) {
    const filename = getFileNameAndLineNumber();
    return `[${level}] ${filename} ${message}`;
}
```

Then declare the transport to use the formatter:

```
new winston.transports.Console({
        level: 'info',
        handleExceptions: true,
        humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: 'level',
        stderrLevels: ['warn', 'error', 'alert'],
        formatter: humanReadableFormatter,
    })
```

To read more about prepareStackTrace read: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces

Comment: I'm getting this is not available in typescript because it's a function

Comment: @xenoterracide making it work with TS is a different issue. Feel free to post a separate question and provide more information so that it's reproducible. I'm less proficient with TS but if you'll tag me I'll take a look.

Comment: Have you checked the functionality of your code? There are mistakes in it.

`const boilerplateLines = line => line &&  line.getFileName() &&(line.getFileName().indexOf('<My Module Name>') &&        (line.getFileName().indexOf('/node_modules/') < 0); `

Comment: @Alex maybe it's confusing but this is an arrow-function. This code works in production for a few years now :) that said, if you think you've found a mistake please help by pinpointing what is it exactly!

Comment: @NirAlfasi `.indexOf('/node_modules/') < 0));`  Missing `)`

Comment: @Alex good catch, probably missed it in the copy&paste - thank you!!!

Comment: Hm the solution looks really nice but i dont think it can ever be portable. After i got it working by solving the "did you create a format instance" issue, i was not able to find a way to determine the "file" of interest. For quick and dirty i now use this.stack[this.stack.length -4].getFileName() but it mostly returns bogus, e.g. the logger itself or similar. Looks like, depending on where i log from, the filename of interest will usually have a different index. Anyway, nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found this code somewhere, yeah but It is working. Use it in a new `winston.js` and then requires that in any file.

```
var winston = require('winston')
var path = require('path')
var PROJECT_ROOT = path.join(__dirname, '..')
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');


const options = {
  file: {
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
    timestamp: true
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    colorize: true,
    timestamp: true
  }
};

var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

logger.stream = {
  write: function (message) {
    logger.info(message)
  }
}

// A custom logger interface that wraps winston, making it easy to instrument
// code and still possible to replace winston in the future.

module.exports.debug = module.exports.log = function () {
  logger.debug.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.info = function () {
  logger.info.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.warn = function () {
  logger.warn.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.error = function () {
  logger.error.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.stream = logger.stream

/**
 * Attempts to add file and line number info to the given log arguments.
 */
function formatLogArguments (args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args)

  var stackInfo = getStackInfo(1)

  if (stackInfo) {
    // get file path relative to project root
    var calleeStr = '(' + stackInfo.relativePath + ':' + stackInfo.line + ')'

    if (typeof (args[0]) === 'string') {
      args[0] = calleeStr + ' ' + args[0]
    } else {
      args.unshift(calleeStr)
    }
  }

  return args
}

/**
 * Parses and returns info about the call stack at the given index.
 */
function getStackInfo (stackIndex) {
  // get call stack, and analyze it
  // get all file, method, and line numbers
  var stacklist = (new Error()).stack.split('\n').slice(3)

  // stack trace format:
  // http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi
  // do not remove the regex expresses to outside of this method (due to a BUG in node.js)
  var stackReg = /at\s+(.*)\s+\((.*):(\d*):(\d*)\)/gi
  var stackReg2 = /at\s+()(.*):(\d*):(\d*)/gi

  var s = stacklist[stackIndex] || stacklist[0]
  var sp = stackReg.exec(s) || stackReg2.exec(s)

  if (sp && sp.length === 5) {
    return {
      method: sp[1],
      relativePath: path.relative(PROJECT_ROOT, sp[2]),
      line: sp[3],
      pos: sp[4],
      file: path.basename(sp[2]),
      stack: stacklist.join('\n')
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/transitive-bullshit/39a7edc77c422cbf8a18

Comment: "somewhere" should get credit by adding a link to the answer!

Comment: I don't have the reference or otherwise, I'll add :)

Comment: I suspect it's copied from here: https://gist.github.com/transitive-bullshit/39a7edc77c422cbf8a18

Answer (score 1):

You can do string operations on

```js
console.log(new Error().stack.split('\n')[1].slice(7));
```

to get line Number and file path too along with function name.

The output would look like

```
AutomationFramework._this.parsingLogic (/Users/user_name/Desktop/something/some-file.js:49:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how I go around it

```js
import winston from 'winston'
const {format } = winston
const { combine, timestamp, printf   } = format;

const myFormat = printf(({ level, message,timestamp , at }) => {

    let on = at.stack.split('\n')[1].slice(7).split('/').pop() ;
    let file = on.split(':')[0]
    let line = on.split(':')[1]
    let data = Date(timestamp).toString().split(' GMT')[0]
    
    return `${level}: [${data}] Hello <yourName>, there is a ${level} message on file:${file}  line ${line} 
      ${message}`;
  });


const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: combine(
    timestamp(),
    myFormat ,
  ),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});
```

on loggin the output will be like

```js
logger.info('wrong file type' , {at : new Error})
//logs
warn: [Thu Aug 18 2022 15:06:28] Hello <yourName>, there is a warn message on file:winston.js  line 7
      >>wrong file type
```

Answer (score 0):

result like

```
2023-03-04 21:19:54.023 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\index.spec.js:7:8 | test message with date parameter 2023-03-09T21:19:54.021Z
2023-03-04 21:19:54.040 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\index.spec.js:68:12 | Authenticating with Salesforce...
2023-03-04 21:19:54.042 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\sfAuth.js:21:10 | Getting credentials from parameter store
2023-03-04 21:19:54.569 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\sfAuth.js:38:10 | Getting access token for Salesforce
2023-03-04 21:19:56.691 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\index.spec.js:78:12 | Creating test subscriptions in Salesforce...
2023-03-04 21:19:58.287 | info | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\index.spec.js:91:12 | Retrieving created subs...
2023-03-04 21:19:58.733 | error | D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\index.spec.js:96:30 | Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\dev\cosmos\e2e\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:293:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

usage

```
const logger = require('./logger.js');

logger.info("test message with date parameter %s", new Date());
...
logger.error(e.stack)
```

logger.js

```
const winston = require('winston');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = winston;

function getCaller() {
    var err;
    try { throw Error('') } catch (e) { err = e; }
    var pattern = /\s*at (Object.)?(silly|debug|verbose|info|warn|error) /;
    var callerLine = err.stack.split("\n").filter(line => pattern.test(line))[0];
    return callerLine.replace(pattern, '').replace(/^\(|\)$/g, '');
}

const logConfig = {
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' }),
        winston.format.printf((log) => `${[log.timestamp]} | ${log.level} | ${getCaller()} | ${log.message}`)
    )
};

const logger = createLogger({
    format: format.combine(
        format.splat(),
        format.simple()
    ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(logConfig)
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
```