# Nodejs Morgan Winston logging print method and line number

Tags: node.js, winston, morgan

I am a novice at nodejs. just trying a logger to print messages similar to Java log4j format where file method & line number can print. But I am unable to file how to print similar way in NodeJS. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952938/get-line-number-and-filename-for-a-log-output)  but not working. I have taken [sample](https://github.com/lioncoding-oss/express-morgan-winston) from GitHub and tried to print the line number. Please guide me. Thanks for your support.