# override Nodejs console to add the line the function were called

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

is there a way to send the line and file a console function has been called?

i got an app with many console log and console error in it. thats a good thing for me, the problem is i need to know from where they came from.

i tried override console.error and add console.trace inside but that just created a recursive call to console error(i guess they both triggered by process strerr)

here is what i have tried

```js
const tempConsoleError = console.error.bind(console);
console.error = function (err) {
    console.log('i am in error')
  
    tempConsoleError(err);
    
    console.trace()
};
console.error('error string ')
```

Comment: might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172822/2417602) will help

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172455/get-name-and-line-of-calling-function-in-node-js

Comment: this doesn`t help me its usess calle and deprcated

Answer (score 0):

ended up writing a packages to do it. is uses the "stack-trace"  and node global

[console-from](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-from)