# How to get the Caller name in node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using arguments.callee.caller.name to get the name of the function where this function is called.

for example:

```
class B {
  a = 0;
  called_from = false;
  setA = (asume)=>{
    this.a = assume;
    this.called_from = arguments.callee.caller.name;
    console.log(this.called_from);
  };

  callA = ()=>{
    this.setA();
  };
}
```

Now I want to get the callA name in the logs.

Comment: This is giving me an error: 
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Comment: I have also tried:

"use strict";

but it is not working

Comment: ```arguments``` object doesn't work in arrow function ```=>```

Comment: @ggorlen - I am trying to compose the logs to capture every activity of an app and so that I am writing logs but I have another function which is printing logs for me in the format I want, so that's why I want to know which method has called the logger to log so, I can log the function name for which actual log needs to be printed.

Thank you for your contribution, let me know if there is something else you can come up with.

Comment: @ArjunSingh - Thank you but I have tried using function () {
     this.called_from = arguments.callee.caller.name;
}.

but it is still not working.

Comment: Logging seems like a good/safe use case. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: ```function B() {
    this.a = 0;
    this.called_from = false;
  this.setA = function(assume){
    this.a = assume;
    this.called_from = arguments.callee.caller;
    console.log(this.called_from);
  };

  this.callA = function (val){
    this.setA(val);
  };
}
var n = new B()
n.callA(10)```

Comment: @ProPrgrammer the error related to strict mode is because all modules in Node execute in strict mode by default, and the caller, callee and arguments properties of functions are not standards compliant - You should pretend they don't exist, essentially. You will either want to generate a stack trace (see Shan's answer) or use a decorator and inspect the `name` property of a function.

Answer (score -4):

Using info from [Accessing line number in V8 JavaScript (Chrome & Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386492/accessing-line-number-in-v8-javascript-chrome-node-js)

you can add some prototypes to provide access to this info from V8;

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '__stack', {
get: function() {
        var orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = function(_, stack) {
            return stack;
        };
        var err = new Error;
        Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
        var stack = err.stack;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
        return stack;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(global, '__line', {
get: function() {
        return __stack[1].getLineNumber();
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(global, '__function', {
get: function() {
        return __stack[1].getFunctionName();
    }
});

function foo() {
    console.log(__line);
    console.log(__function);
}

foo()
```

Comment: Returns '28' and 'foo', respectively.

Comment: copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172455/get-name-and-line-of-calling-function-in-node-js/14172822 so -1