# Get a source file and line of any function using Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

Some guy points out that [Firebug does display the source file and line for event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6885659/607407). I have a pseudo-class defined somewhere within 11 script files. Could I use Firebug to find out which file did I put it into? *

It's embarrassing when you write a code and you just can't find it while executing it...

<sub>* Pseudo-class is just a function that keeps it's namespace after execution. If I put it very simply...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To find the code you can simply use the [search field](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Search_Field) at the top right of Firebug when you are at the *Script* panel.

[image: Search field within Firebug]

Ensure you have checked the option *Multiple Files* within the search options, then type the name of your "pseudo-class". You can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times to switch through the matches.

When you found the code, the name of the file is displayed within the panel toolbar. Hover it to get the full URL of the file as tooltip.

[image: Script location button]